# Java Array list won't update when within button

Tags: java, button, arraylist

I'm new to Java (and stackoverflow...), so this might be obvious but couldn't find similar when I searched for it (if I missed it please don't hesitate to just link me the solution!)

I'm struggling with trying to make my Array list update within a button. It keeps saying 'Cannot resolve symbol fileEntry' when I use it in onSensorChanged (I used to have it defined outside the button but it wouldn't update it when I clicked the starting button), and it also says 'Variable fileEntry is never used' within the button. See code below :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    starting_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
    starting_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ArrayList fileEntry = new ArrayList();
```

And this is where I am trying to use it:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    fileEntry.add(sensorEvent.values[0] + "," + sensorEvent.values[1] + "," + sensorEvent.values[2] + "\r");
}
```

What I would like it to do is to have a new fileEntry (i.e. clear it) every time I click on the starting button.

I know my code is far from being perfect, sorry in advance!

Comment: looks like your Array doesn't have the scope it needs: if you declare the variable inside a method it can only be used inside that method, you need to pull the Array out to the scope where both methods can use it, probably to the instance scope.

Comment: fileEntry looks like it is out of scope, your onSensorChanged method has no way of reaching the fileEntry list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your ArrayList as a property in your activity class like this in order to use it in your different methods :

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity() {
    private ArrayList fileEntry;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fileEntry = new ArrayList();

        starting_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        starting_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something with your fileEntry
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        fileEntry.add(sensorEvent.values[0] + "," + sensorEvent.values[1] + "," + sensorEvent.values[2] + "\r");
    }    
}
```

The scope of your property will now be limited to your class, and not simply your onClick method.